# How do I save the position of draggable & resizeable elements?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm building a site which allows users to create an html page which can then be saved and shared on another site.  I want them to be able to resize and drag the page elements.  I can do this using jQuery, but I'm not sure how I then save that so that when the page is viewed elsewhere, it looks the same.

I haven't decided yet how to store the page info, but what I'm thinking is that I can store each element in the database along with its absolute position, and its contents.  Does that sound like a good plan?

If so, how do I get the position for the div to pass to the php so that it can be saved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

JQueryUI Resizable has an event called `resize` that you can use:

```
var resposition = '';

$('#divresize').resizable({
   //options...
   resize: function(event,ui){
      resposition = ui.position;
   }
});
```

The same occurs with JQueryUI Draggable and its event `drag`:

```
var dragposition = '';

$('#divdrag').draggable({
   // other options...
   drag: function(event,ui){
      dragposition = ui.position;
   }
});
```

`resposition` and `dragposition` is going to be arrays. You can see it working here: http://jsbin.com/uvuzi5

EDIT: using a form, you can save `dragposition` and `resposition` into hidden inputs

```
var inputres = '<input type="hidden" id="resposition" value="'+resposition.left+','+resposition.top+'"/>'
$('#myform').append(inputres);
var inputdrag = '<input type="hidden" id="dragposition" value="'+dragposition.left+','+dragposition.top+'"/>'
$('#myform').append(inputdrag);
```

And in your PHP file to handle the form:

```
$dragposition = $_GET['dragposition'];
$resposition = $_GET['resposition'];
$dragposition = explode(',',$dragposition);
$resposition = explode(',',$resposition);
```

Finally, both variables should be arrays with top and left attributes:

```
$dragposition => [top,left] attributes from draggable
$resposition => [top,left] attributes from resizable
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.  How do I save those positions when I save the page?  Let's assume the user does all this and then clicks 'Save'... how do I get the form to pass in the position and size elements?

Comment: Thank you, that makes it clearer.  Will give it a go!  Thanks again, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: However I like this answer so much, I can't get it to work with the Resizable. Even not in your example. What I need to do, is get the width and the height of the div. When I get the positions working that should not be to hard though.

Comment: @FranVerona - thanks for this answer. Which part of the code initialises the objects with the same positions/sizes as before? Or is that not yet part of your code?

Comment: `localStorage` would be a good place to store it, rather than submitting it to the server, especially if you're dealing with a large user base

Answer (score 1):

> you have to save position at some where so that you can get position
>   details when next time you open page.

**option 1:** you can store html elements position details in "localStorage" its default browser storage.
[**Example:**](https://jsfiddle.net/v685v9t6/954/)  [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/v685v9t6/954/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/css/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <script src="dist/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        var positions = JSON.parse(localStorage.positions || "{}");
        $(function() {
            var d = $("[id=draggable]").attr("id", function(i) {
                return "draggable_" + i
            })
            $.each(positions, function(id, pos) {
                $("#" + id).css(pos)
            })

            d.draggable({
                containment: "#wrapper",
                scroll: false,
                stop: function(event, ui) {
                    positions[this.id] = ui.position
                    localStorage.positions = JSON.stringify(positions)
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content draggable" style="height:100px;width:100px;float:left">Div1</div>
        <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content draggable" style="height:100px;width:100px;float:left">Div2</div>
        <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content draggable" style="height:100px;width:100px;float:left">Div3</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**option 2:** you can store html elements position details in "your database"

Comment: Could we the code for API? Save it to the database?