# Drag and drop table rows

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to figure out how I can make the rows drag and droppable that way it will update the database with the new sort order.

http://jsfiddle.net/SwQLF/

This is dealing with the dataTables plugin though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I save the position of draggable & resizeable elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304276/how-do-i-save-the-position-of-draggable-resizeable-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304276/how-do-i-save-the-position-of-draggable-resizeable-elements) in your situation, just ignore the information about resizable.

Ad@m

Answer (score 1):

jQueryUI got Draggable and Droppable types.

Demos:

- http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/
- http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

This should help you create what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Now there is [row reordering addon](http://jquery-datatables-row-reordering.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html) for [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) to reorder rows via drag&drop with corresponding updates and callbacks.