# Create a user-customisable navigation with javascript/jQuery and local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'd like to create a user-customisable navigation - kind of a 'personisable dashboard' for the CMS I'm working on. The user would be able to choose from a list of links to sections like 'edit page', 'lookup user', and add / remove the links that they user the most to their own dashboard. For my choice of links, I have all of the available links that the user has permission for in a hidden div.

I am thinking of jQuery UI droppable for the interface (this example is close: http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager).

Finally I will need to save the User's choices and for this I'd like to use localStorage or cookies as I don't have access to the server-side code.

My questions are:
Does anyone know of anything with a lighter footprint than jQuery UI for the drag and drop?

Does anyone know of any examples that include the saving of the user's choices using local Storage or cookies?

Answer (score 1):

Not an incredibly specific question, but I'll do my best. I've worked with page customizations, jquery, jquery ui, and HTML5 local storage a good deal, and one of the big things to consider in implementation is your storage choice. While it's certainly possible (I presume, since I don't know what CMS or any real details) to use these pieces and roll a customization solution, you may run into issues trying to make an acceptable solution with Local Storage.

Here's the issue: by  design, HTML5 Local Storage will allow you to track your changes across browser sessions so you can maintain the user's navigation choices. However, if the user tries to access their same site from another browser, all their customizations will not exist in that context.

If you are set on using Local Storage anyway, be sure to check if it's supported on the user's browser (maybe using [Modernizr](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#modernizr)). Otherwise, I've found the jquery and jquery ui libraries to be sufficient in and of themselves to make the needed DOM manipulations. Admittedly I cannot offer much more in terms of suggestions without knowing more about your particular setup.

Comment: Hi, Sorry I wasn't very clear. I'm fine with the browser constraints - I'm already using some sessionStorage. Eventually I want to save the settings against the user serverside, but for now I can't make those changes to the code on the server so local storage or cookies will suffice. You're right that jQuery UI can probably do what I need (droppable looks good) and actually that has helped me as I just found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304276/how-do-i-save-the-position-of-draggable-resizeable-elements

Comment: I edited my question to try to make it more useful.

Comment: Great, glad you've found a good direction there. The only thing I would use in addition to droppable would be the jquery ui menu as well, but I'm sure that's a given ;) Looks like you're well on your way, but if you run into anything while you give that a shot, come on back.

Comment: also, if you found this helpful, please consider upvoting it :)